# Вопросы по поводу шифра Вернама

Tags: криптография, шифрование

Здравствуйте! Появились следующие вопросы:

1. Почему для использования шифра необходма истинно случайная последовательность? Почему нельзя использовать псевдослучайные последовательности?
2. Является ли последовательность символов, придуманная человеком (*например последовательность `anaskbbhbfyj`, придуманная мной только что*) истинно случайной?

Comment: Во времена второй мировой для генерации шифроблокнотов были специальные люди, которые сидели целыми днями и тянули шары с номерами. И при этом криптоаналитики Ленгли были не довольны случайностью этих данных, потому что люди иногда ленились и пытались не вытягивая шаров заполнять блокноты ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. У псевдослучайной последовательности есть закономерности.
   Доказательство невозможности расшифровать шифр Вермана: если мы переберём все возможные ключи, то получим все возможные сообщения. Выбирать нам не из чего.
   А вот если есть закономерность, то выбрать мы сможем.
2. Никакая последовательность, придуманная человеком не является случайной.
   Есть частотный алгоритм игры на основе нескольких последних значений - против человека он всегда выигрывает при длительной игре.

Answer (score 2):

Псевдослучайная последовательность - это значения некоторой рекуррентной функции с неким инициализирующим значением. Соответственно зная это значение (обычно это 32 или 64 бита) можно повторно сгенерировать всю ключевую последовательность и прочитать сообщение

Comment: Надо заметить, что число внутренних состояний генератора может быть много больше числа сидов. Например для Mersenne Twister это так.

Answer (score 1):

Число внутренних состояний ГПСЧ много ниже, чем число возможных ключей, им порождаемых. Следовательно проще искать нужное состояние ГПСЧ, чем ключ.

"anaskbbhbfyj" оценить проблематично, нужно знать алфавит. Но мне кажется что алфавит - "a-z" и тогда о случайности говорить нельзя: на 24 символа будет около 6 букв "b".

Comment: С первым вопросом разобрался, спасибо. Но несовсем понял, что Вы имели ввиду, касательно второго вопроса.

Comment: @Eanmos Напишите генератор "случайных" строк и посмотрите как часто на строку в 12 символов у вас будет приходиться 3 одинаковых буквы.

Comment: @ВладимирМартянов, может такое и будет случаться не часто, но это не является критерием случайности (поправьте меня, если я не прав). В случайной последовательности может быть все, что угодно, хотя 50 букв `a` подряд.

Comment: @Eanmos Дело в вероятности. Такой перекос практически наверняка говорит о том, что либо генератора вовсе не было, либо он с особенностями.

Comment: И все-таки, можно ли считать последовательность чисел или символов, сгенерированную человеком, истинно случайной?

Comment: @Eanmos я считаю что нельзя

Comment: А есть ли какое-то общепринятое мнение на этот счет?

Comment: @Eanmos поищите, но я почему-то уверен что оно будет таким же.